# What's the optimal way of measuring the error of quantitative estimates, across question sets?

Tags: estimators, aggregation

My research relates to situations in which individuals make a quantitative estimate and then make a second quantitative estimate, perhaps after some manipulation. Minimally I am interested in comparing:

A) The error of a first estimate
B) The error of a second estimate
C) The error of the average of the first and second estimates.

I want to compare the efficacy of different manipulations, and also the extent to which changing question sets affects the efficacy of a particular manipulation. The question sets vary widely; in some question sets you can get responses that are huge outliers (e.g. answers to a question like "How many kilograms of fuel were on the Space Shuttle orbiter at take-off?") while with other question sets big outliers can't really exist (e.g. answers to a question like "What percentage of the world's airports are in the United States?").

I've seen the Mean Squared Error frequently used in this context (e.g. [this paper](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53771404/Vul%20Pashler%202008.pdf)), and also the Root Mean Square Error. Others have favoured a method based on the median (e.g. [this paper](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53771404/Herzog%20Herwig%202009.pdf)), and I've also seen the Mean Absolute Deviation used (e.g. [this paper](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53771404/Muller-Trede%202011.pdf)).

I'm keen to know which method should be preferred, or if no method is preferable over the others how I could make some principled argument that that is the case.